# how to implement tabs in react with using any library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

could you please tell me how to implement tabs in react with using any library ?
I follow this link and tried to make tabs 
https://toddmotto.com/creating-a-tabs-component-with-react/
but not succeeded.
Here is my code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/D9Q6qWPEn

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Tabs extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state= {
      selected:0
    }
  }
   _renderContent() {
    return (
      <div className="tabs__content">
         {this.props.children[this.state.selected]}
      </div>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div className="tabs">
        {this._renderContent()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Tabs;
```

**I am not able to show tabs and it there individual contents after click**
any update ?

Comment: Do you experience any particular problem?

Comment: @zerkms I am not able to show tabs and it there individual contents after click

Answer (score 0):

> if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail

Don't try to use React for everything. Not only is this a bad practice. React was never intended to fit that purpose. Creating tabs is 90% CSS and only 10% JS (controlling which one gets the "active" state.

I created an example that implements tabs 100% using CSS, It doesn't work well since only *after* a tab is clicked the content is shown, there is no default.

If you wanted to automate this (e.g.) in an React component The only thing you have to do is bind a tab click to an active state a classname representing the *active* state (e.g.: tab--active). And create a default.

```css
.tabs__list-item {
  display: inline;
}

.tab {
  display: none;
}

.tab:target {  /* Only works if tab is clicked, can be fixed with React. */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="tabs">
  <ul class="tabs__list">
    <li class="tabs__list-item"><a class="tabs__link" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li class="tabs__list-item"><a class="tabs__link" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li class="tabs__list-item"><a class="tabs__link" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section class="tab" id="tab1">
  <h1>Tab 1 header</h1>
  <p>This is the content of tab 1.</p>
</section>

<section class="tab" id="tab2">
  <h1>Tab 2 header</h1>
  <p>This is the content of tab 2.</p>
</section>

<section class="tab" id="tab3">
  <h1>Tab 3 header</h1>
  <p>This is the content of tab 3.</p>
</section>
```

In short:

- Write the HTML structure / CSS markup first
- Observe missing logic
- Implement missing logic using the best tool.

React may be a valid tool for this purpose but start by having React rendering your HTML and CSS. If you can't get the "wiring" logic to work open a question indicating what specific problem you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you just want to display *labels* for your tabs.

You can do this in many ways in `React` but without changing your code too much, you can accomplish this task by changing `render()` method of `Tabs` component, like below:

```
setTab(index) {
  this.setState({
    selected: index,
  });
}

_renderLabels() {
  return this.props.children.map((child, index) => (
    <div key={child.props.label} onClick={() => { this.setTab(index) }}>
      {child.props.label}
    </div>
  ));
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="tabs">
      {this._renderLabels()}
      {this._renderContent()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

What we do here is basically rendering *labels* based on `props.children`. For each label we append click handler.

You could improve this code by creating specific components like `TabPane`, `TabLabel`.

Full code of `Tabs` component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Tabs extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selected: 0
    };
  }

  setTab(index) {
    this.setState({
      selected: index,
    });
  }

  _renderContent() {
    return (
      <div className="tabs__content">
        {this.props.children[this.state.selected]}
      </div>
    );
  }

  _renderLabels() {
    return this.props.children.map((child, index) => (
      <div key={child.props.label} onClick={() => { this.setTab(index) }}>
        {child.props.label}
      </div>
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="tabs">
        {this._renderLabels()} 
        {this._renderContent()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tabs;
```

**Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/pRvG6K0r

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this and is working awesome:

I'm using a functional component with Hooks.

```
const Tabs = () => {
  const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState('first-tab');

  const toggleTab = () => {
    switch (currentTab) {
      case 'first-tab':
        return <FirstTab />;
      case 'second-tab':
        return <SecondTab />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h3 onClick={() => setCurrentTab('first-tab')}>First Tab</h3>
        <h3 onClick={() => setCurrentTab('second-tab')}>Second Tab</h3>
      </div>
      {toggleTab()}
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can add more components if you want.

---

Psdt: And if you want to add styles to the Current Tab Title you can create another useState Hook, something like "isActive" and this set it up on the  tag classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Tabs = () => {
  const tabsData = [
    { id: 0, tabName: "first tab", tabData: "first tab data" },
    { id: 1, tabName: "second tab", tabData: "second tab data" },
    { id: 2, tabName: "third tab", tabData: "third tab data" },
  ];

  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(false);

  const tabClick = (index) => {
    setActiveIndex(index);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {tabsData.map((tab) => {
          return (
            <li key={tab.id} onClick={() => tabClick(tab.id)}>
              {tab.tabName}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <ul>
        {tabsData.map((tab) => {
          if (tab.id === activeIndex) {
        return <li key={tab.id}>{tab.tabData}</li>;
      }
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```